# How do I build a blog pages listing with nextJs?

Tags: next.js

I'm porting my static blog from Jekyll to nextjs and so far everything is nice except one element : I'm trying to build a page listing component that displays page 1, 2, 3... under the index.js where all posts are shown (10 by 10).

The component works and I created a /pages/page/[id].js that's supposed to display the pages. The component is functional except when I export to static, I'm getting only one page on the folder /page/2.html.

So my question is: how can I generate a static set of pages - because right now it's not generating all the pages ?

EDIT => the code I'm using in file /pages/page/[id].js

```
const allPosts = getAllPosts()

export async function getStaticProps() {
  
  return {
    props: { allPosts },
  }
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  return {
    paths: [
      { params: { id: '2' } },
    ],
    fallback: true,
  }
}

export default function Page({allPosts}) {

  let returnData ;

  // get the url query => /conformite-cnil
  const router = useRouter();
  //console.log(router);
  
  if(allPosts != undefined){

    const router = useRouter();
    let currentPageIs = router.query.id;
    const currentPageNumber = currentPageIs.replace(/\D/g, '');
    let postStart = (currentPageNumber * 10) - 10;
    let postEnd = (currentPageNumber * 10 + 9) - 10;

    const currentPosts = allPosts.slice(postStart,postEnd);

    returnData = (  
        <>
          <PostListing posts={currentPosts} />
          <PostPagination posts={allPosts} currentPage={currentPageNumber - 1} />
        </>  
      )
  }
  

  return (
    <>
    <Navbar />
    <div className="container">
      <main>
        
        <div className="row ">
          <div className="col-sm-8 p-5">
            {returnData}
          </div>
          <div className="col-sm-4 p-5 no_toc_section ">
              <RightSideBar />
          </div>
        </div> 
      </main>
    </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you give more information on how you're exporting to static?

Comment: I'm exporting through next build && next export

Comment: You're only building the page with `id: '2'` in `getStaticPaths`. `fallback: true` and ISR are not supported when using `next export` - see https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export#unsupported-features. You'll have to pre-build all pages in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Using a slug `/pages/page/[id]` means you're dynamically loading each page. I don't think you can statically generate and export the page like that, because on build time, only one page is available because of your use of `[id]`. If you want to go about it this same way, you need to create the pages one by one. i.e `/pages/page/1`, `pages/page/2`, and so on. That would work the way you want it to work.

Honestly, I don't think it's necessary to export statically. Nextjs already takes care of it for you and generates static pages for you by default during build. Keep your build steps like this:

```
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
```

Comment: Strangely, one page was generated like this in HTML in my configuration. Thanks for your answer by the way !